# Ubuntu advantage, Certified Windows drivers for KVM guests

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I have Ubuntu advantage essential for our server, does anyone knows where I can download "Certified Windows drivers for KVM guests"?

Johan

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find them at https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers the top part goes to the Windows drivers and at the bottom takes you to how you can sign the drivers yourself.  You can ignore the RedHat / Fedora part.

Comment: So you mean that Ubuntu don't have any of their own signed drivers that Ubuntu advantage says?

Comment: @johndoe You might want to contact Canonical themselves then.  We are just volunteers here that try to help people on their way.